# Problems installing Sitecore Habitat

Tags: installation, habitat

I am trying to setup Sitecore Habitat, i.e. just get it running and nothing else. I have followed the [installation instructions](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/docs/01-Getting-Started.md#getting-started) meticulously but have been met with nothing but trouble. Not quite my definition of simplicity but anyway. I managed to overcome all of these so far

1. *Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server* wouldn't connect because install-xp0 does not specify username and password which was required (at least in my case).
2. Solr connection would not work because of TLS/SSL negotiation. Had to explicitly set the TLS version in install-xp0 to get it to work.

Now the script is asking for *.\build\assets\Prerequisites.json* and the file is nowhere to be found. Where am I supposed to get all these files that are listed [here](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/docs/01-Getting-Started.md#1-installing-sitecore)? I have cloned the repository and downloaded the required version of Sitecore as a ZIP archive and placed it into the assets directory as instructed.

Comment: Are you getting the issue with the installation of Sitecore or integrating habitat solution with a sitecore instance? Which Sitecore version you are using?

Comment: I am following the instructions as outlined [here](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/docs/01-Getting-Started.md#getting-started). As such I downloaded Sitecore Version 9.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specified files are within the Sitecore XP0 zip which you downloaded. The Sitecore Install Framework, which Habitat invokes for you, requires both the install WDPs and the configuration JSON files embedded in that zip.

The Habitat [Getting Started](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started) instructions were previously unclear as to the need to unzip this file into `\build\assets\`.

[image: First Unzip]

Further, you must then unzip the *XP0 Configuration files* into the same folder (*Extract Here*):

[image: Second Unzip]

I've updated the [Getting Started](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started) guide to clarify this.

As for your other issues with the install script, if you wouldn't mind reporting them as [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/issues), including your required changes, we can further investigate, as I have not seen these previously reported.

Comment: Thanks alot, that makes things a lot clearer